# How to make sections of a drop down list coloured in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, colors, excel-2016, vba

I'm making an workbook that stores customer orders.

The way I have it structured so far is a drop down list with all the products in. So a work sheet reads

"Customer Name" "Contact Number" "Product 1" "Product 2" "Product 3" etc.

As I say, all products are listed in the same drop down. But as there is many different products, I wanted to make it colour coded. So I have different kinds of Poultry, Beef, Lamb, Deli, Bakery. Each section I want to be colour coded differently. I have found how to do it on an individual scale using conditional formatting, however there are that many products that doing it individually would be way to time consuming, and I don't have the patience.

So my question is how can I get Poultry products to be one colour, beef products another colour and so on.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single conditional formatting rule for many different options. You don't have to have a ton of different rules for each individual option. See image below for an example of how you could use one conditional formatting rule to format `Hamburger`, `Steak`, and `Filet` the same way.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts This is true.